# I need to make the muzzle flip by the camera angle but still having both muzzle models

Tags: modeling, armature, camera, mirror

[image]

I want this model to behave like how Sonic Unleashed's Sonic Model does in game: It features two muzzles (mouth area models), and one of them is chosen per shot based on the camera angle.

The difference between the two muzzles is mainly that the mouth is placed on different sides of Sonic’s face (because his mouth is not centered like Blaze or real creatures).

Thus, whichever one has the mouth on the side facing the camera needs to be the one, and only one, being shown. How can I achieve this? They are separate objects from each other and the rest of the body, parented to the armature.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I understand I think, but not many people that don’t know the sonic model will. “Muzzle” is not common terminology.

Comment: What I think you need to do is figure out which side of the head bone’s front facing axis (local posed space) the camera is on, and drive object render visibility (or object scale sign) based on that. How to do that… 

Comment: I need to know how I need to figure out the side of the muzzle/ mouth bone's front facing axis with 2 models for each direction: one for the left side ( Muzzle_L ) and one for the right side ( Muzzle_R), without any import, and with armatures.

Comment: What do I mean with the muzzle? I'm talking about an animal muzzle, you know like a snout of a dog, however, Sonic's muzzle has two separate models, but one is used with the armature depending at the camera angle: one for the left side, and one for the right side.